# Undefined control sequence \begin{abstract} but abstract appears

Tags: document-classes, abstract

I'm using a customised (not by me) document class called `geogthesis` to produce my Geography PhD thesis.

When I compile the file I get an error saying:

```
Undefined control sequence. [\begin{abstract}]
```

However, the PDF actually builds fine, and includes the abstract - which is strange. Still, I'd like to get rid of the error (errors when building my thesis scare me!)

I'm using the LaTeX file below, combined with the [geogthesis.cls file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gcka5ehgmdfnjeg/geogthesis.cls):

```
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\documentclass{geogthesis}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title      {TITLE HERE}
\authors    {\texorpdfstring{\href{mailto:r.t.wilson@soton.ac.uk}{Robin Wilson}}{}}
\supervisor {\texorpdfstring {\href{mailto:blah@soton.ac.uk}{Blah}}{}}
\cosupervisor {\texorpdfstring {\href{mailto:blah@soton.ac.uk}{Blah}}{}}
\addresses  {\deptname\\\univname}
\date       {\today}
\subject    {Remote Sensing}
\keywords   {keywords}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\small{Blah blah}
\end{abstract}

\mainmatter


Main text here!

\end{document}
```

Comment: the reason the text of the abstract appeared is that the control sequence reported as undefined is simply ignored, but the text following it isn't.  however, as noted by daleif, `\small` doesn't take an argument, so your "Main text here!" would also appear in small type, unless the `\mainmatter` command reset the primary font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember `\small does not take arguments.

There is at least one error in that class.

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}
{
\btypeout{Abstract Page}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\null\vfil
\begin{center}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
{\normalsize \UNIVNAME \par}
{\normalsize {ABSTRACT} \par}
\medskip
{\normalsize \FACNAME \par}
{\normalsize \DEPTNAME \par}
\medskip
{\large Doctor of Philosophy (PhD)\par}
\medskip % <-- typo said \medsckip
{\normalsize\bf \@title \par}
\medskip
{\normalsize by \authornames \par}
\medskip
\end{center}
}
{
\vfil\vfil\vfil\null
\cleardoublepage
}

\makeatother
```

Comment: Changing the abstract bit of the class as you suggested didn't seem to work, but changing `\renewenvironment{abstract}` to `\newenvironment{abstract}` made it all work with no errors. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, adding the Table of Contents back into the document (I had deliberately made the smallest, simplest example for this question) gives me various errors like `You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode. [\tableofcontents]` and `Missing $ inserted. [\tableofcontents]`. From what I can see elsewhere online, this may be caused by problems with @'s. I don't really understand how this works, but I've tried removing the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` commands and that hasn't fixed it. I can't find any `\makeatletter` or `\makeatother` commands in the cls file. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't mess with/remove things if you do not know what they do. Add the above to the preamble and your example compiles just fine. The `\make...` pair is needed because the code contain `@` in their name indicating these are internal.

Comment: Delete the `.aux` and the `.toc` files and recompile, then `\tableofcontents` works just fine for me.

Comment: Should the code above be in the preamble then? I assumed it was meant to replace the equivalent bit in the `geogthesis.cls` file. I've tried including it in the preamble and using the original geogthesis.cls file that I linked to in my original question, and it all compiles fine. Thank you.

What is the best way to get these modifications into the original class file? I'd like to send a fixed version back to my colleague who generally distributes it to PhD students in the department.

Comment: Basically, you should not touch the `.cls` file. Report back to your colleague that there is a problem with it, and refer to the typo. You might also suggest that the `ifpdf` package is loaded by the class, instead of the `\ifpdf` construction included inside the class.